# How do I delete a document after giving it to the client

Tags: java, file, jsf, xpages, ssjs

I have a button which generates docx files for the client. The problem I have encountered is that I'm unable to delete the generated file after giving it to the client. The server-side technology is JSF (XPages). The button invokes the following code:

```
var v = new ru.generate.doc.generateDoc();
v.generateReport2();
```

The `generateReport2()` method invokes 2 important methods the `generateFromTemplateAndReturnPath(String template)`:

```
private String generateFromTemplateAndReturnPath(String pathToTemplate) 
{
          XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(pathToTemplate));
          String pathToFinalResult = FilenameUtils.getFullPath(pathToTemplate) + "reportTest.docx";
          FileOutputStream fous = new FileOutputStream(pathToFinalResult);
          document.write(fous);
          fous.close();
          return pathToFinalResult;
}
```

and  the `giveDocumentForClient(String pathToCompleteFile)` method which gives the report to the client:

```
private void giveDocumentForClient(String pathToCompleteFile) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException 
{
      String fn = new File(pathToCompleteFile).getName();
      XspHttpServletResponse response = (XspHttpServletResponse)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
      response.setContentType(URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fn));
      response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fn);
      OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
      output.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(new File(pathToCompleteFile))));
      output.close();
      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete(); 
}
```

After this method is done I try to inkove this inside `generateReport2()`:

```
new File(pathToCompleteFile).delete()
```

And this method returns false regardless what I do. I have also tried:

`FileDeleteStrategy.FORCE.delete(new File(pathToSubstitutedDoc))`

But  still no result.

Methods like canRead(), canWrite(), canExecute() always return true. SecurityManager also executes methods without any exceptions. What is the problem?

Comment: What you should consider: instead of fous for writing to a file, why not use response.getOutputStream() there (pass it as parameter to that function). Doesn’t leave you with a file to deal with. The name of the file in content-disposition can be chosen freely. Name it to make sense for the user. E.g include the date in the name (if that makes sense)

Answer (score 2):

Well, it was really simple. I forgot that FileInputStream should be closed too.

The method should look like this:

```
private void giveDocumentForClient(String pathToCompleteFile) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException 
{
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToCompleteFile));
      String fn = new File(pathToCompleteFile).getName();
      XspHttpServletResponse response = (XspHttpServletResponse)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
      response.setContentType(URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fn));
      response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fn);
      OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
      output.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(fis));
      output.close();
      fis.close();
      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the better Files class:

```
  OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
  Files.copy(Paths.get(pathToCompleteFile), output);

  Files.delete(Paths.get(pathToCompleteFile));
```

Though that probably does not solve the problem.

If not deletable, either the file is ***not closed*** during its generation. As the application is still running, the file handle is maintained. This especially
could be the case under Windows.

(Or it would be a matter of file rights. But that you checked: *SecurityManager* and *canRead*.)

Then there are some esoteric cases, like a *virus scanner*.

---

After a looking at the generating code; do:

```
      try (FileOutputStream fous = new FileOutputStream(pathToFinalResult)) {
          document.write(fous);
      } // Automatic fous.close() even on exception or return.
```

This try-with-resources ensures automatic closing, even on Exception/break/return.

Comment: I forgot to mention something please take a look

Comment: Ah, use Java version under 7th :(

Comment: Then a try-finally-close block. Did not see any exception handling (probably simplification for the question.)

Comment: Just to make sure: you concatenate the file name to a path, does it end with `/`?

Comment: Hmm, I think the problem has to do with HTTP. After clicking "Create report" button, I cannot delete the file even in Windows. It gives me "The action can't be completed because the file is open in nhttp.exe". But as soon as I hit refresh button in the browser everything is fine - file is able to be deleted..

Comment: You are probably right; I always generate the doc in core and immediate stream it out. In fact I am unsure about response's OutputStream.close() - whether it even should be called. Maybe it has no effect. And the actual transfer takes longer. Or I use temp files.